# Ionic 2 rootPage not showing

Tags: tabs, ionic2

I'm new to Ionic and just started a new project. I picked the template with the 3 tabs at the bottom but now I want a new startpage.
I created a page called LoginPage but when I try to swap TabsPage for LoginPage it just shows an empty screen.
Here are the files

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
import { StatusBar, Splashscreen } from 'ionic-native';
import { LoginPage } from '../pages/login/login';


@Component({
  templateUrl: 'app.html'
})
export class MyApp {
  rootPage = LoginPage;

  constructor(platform: Platform) {
    platform.ready().then(() => {
      // Okay, so the platform is ready and our plugins are available.
      // Here you can do any higher level native things you might need.
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
      Splashscreen.hide();
    });
  }
}
```

login.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core'; 
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
    selector: 'page-login',
    templateUrl: 'login.html'
})
export class LoginPage {

    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {

    }

}
```

app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule, ErrorHandler } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicApp, IonicModule, IonicErrorHandler } from 'ionic-angular';
import { MyApp } from './app.component';
import { SettingsPage } from '../pages/settings/settings';
import { ContactPage } from '../pages/contact/contact';
import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';
import { TabsPage } from '../pages/tabs/tabs';
import {LoginPage} from "../pages/login/login";

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
      SettingsPage,
      ContactPage,
      HomePage,
      TabsPage,
      LoginPage
  ],
  imports: [
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp)
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
      SettingsPage,
      ContactPage,
      HomePage,
      TabsPage,
      LoginPage
  ],
  providers: [{provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler}]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

If there are other files you need to see, just say so and I will add them.
Thanks in adventage.

Comment: where are you setting tabspage and can you add the component?

Comment: I didn't set the tabspage i'm only using loginpage at the moment

Comment: do you get any errors in browser console?

Comment: no I tried to run the page on a blank app first and that worked fine

Comment: The html or ts file? But I just want to show the loginpage without the tabs.

Comment: Ah.. sorry you mean your *loginpage* is not showing..I thought the the reverse at first

Comment: Can you add the logn page html?

Comment: Did you add the login page using ionic cli or manually in the file explorer?

Comment: I added it manually. I don't think there is a problem with the html as the exact same code works in the blank app. There I swapped the example code with this.

Comment: Not sure why you are not getting anything in the logs.. you are using angular 1 syntax `ng-click` and `ng-model` here. Ionic 2 is based on angular 2 not 1.

Comment: Thanks for the note, I changed it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the login page using ionic CLI

```
$ ionic g page login
```

Then add the page in `app.module.ts` and edit `app.component.ts` like you mentioned

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
import { StatusBar, Splashscreen } from 'ionic-native';

import { LoginPage } from '../pages/login/login';


@Component({
  templateUrl: 'app.html'
})
export class MyApp {
  rootPage = LoginPage;

  constructor(platform: Platform) {
    platform.ready().then(() => {
      // Okay, so the platform is ready and our plugins are available.
      // Here you can do any higher level native things you might need.
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
      Splashscreen.hide();
    });
  }
}
```